# Can a spelling error be corrected when block quoting?

Tags: discussion, blockquote

When quoting from another website in a block quote, is it acceptable to correct a spelling error.

For example, **automatically** instead of **augomatically**. If so, should you indicate the corrected error, in italics or in bold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual way is to indicate the corrections you've made with [(square) brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Usage_in_published_text), e.g.

> The value is au[t]omatically determined.

If it is somehow important that the typo is kept, use the word [sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic#Formatting):

> The value is augomatically [sic] determined.

These practices are widely understood in the publishing world, even before Internet existed, and have become quite common on the Internet as well. Stack Exchange doesn't have its own rules/practices, other than that if you quote another Stack Exchange post it's appreciated if you (suggest an edit to) correct the source.

Comment: *The Chicago Manual of Style* (13.7) lists several things that can all be modified from the original when providing a quotation. Such things include changing single quotation marks to double quotation marks, an initial letter being capitalized or put in lowercase (in order to fit the flow of the surrounding text), punctuation marks at the end being omitted or changed to a period or comma to fit the surrounding text, and some others. It also specifically says that "obvious typographic errors may be corrected silently (without comment or sic) . . ." There are some caveats to that.

Comment: "Obvious typographic errors may be corrected silently (without comment or *sic*; see 13.61), unless the passage quoted is from an older work or a manuscript or other unpublished source where idiosyncrasies of spelling are generally preserved. If spelling and punctuation are modernized or altered for clarity, readers must be so informed in a note, in a preface, or elsewhere."